# Import MS Access schema to Oracle

Tags: ms-access, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration

I found [this guide](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/msaccess/migrate_microsoft_access_otn.htm) using Oracle Sql Developer to import MS Access XML schema files to Oracle.
But there have been a lot of changes in Sql Developer since the guide was written.

Does anyone know if it's still possible to migrate MS Access to Oracle using latest Sql Developer tools?

Comment: there was a tool **bullzip** or something it can migrate access to other providers.

Comment: thatjeffsmith suggestion sounds great. But you could also pretty easily write your own migrator if you got a day.

Answer (score 1):

No, we no longer support Access 'migrations' to Oracle in the current code base.

Java deprecated the odbc-jdbc bridge, and we were relying on that for Access connections.

You would need an old copy of SQL Developer (v3.1) to use this feature.

Now, if you have a SQL Server instance handy, you could move it over there, and then use SQL Developer to migrate the data to Oracle.

If it's a simple db, you could offload the tables to flat files (CSV), and use SQL Developer to create the tables from that.